# Save Cascade many To many Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I'm following the Documentation About Authentication. Now I want implement Role

This is my entities

User.php

```
/**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getRoles () {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }

    public function getRoles2 () {
        return $this->roles;
    }
```

Than i Have three tables

> users user_role role

roles

```
<?php

namespace ADV\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Role
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ADV\UserBundle\Entity\RoleRepository")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Add users
     *
     * @param \ADV\UserBundle\Entity\User $users
     * @return Role
     */
    public function addUser(\ADV\UserBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users[] = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove users
     *
     * @param \ADV\UserBundle\Entity\User $users
     */
    public function removeUser(\ADV\UserBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($users);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

I create two form, userType and Roletype, and UserType "embed" the roleType

```
->add('roles', 'collection', array(

                'type' => new RoleType()
            ))
```

My Controller:

```
public function registrationAction (Request $request) {

        $user = new User();
        $role = new Role();


        $user->getRoles2()->add($role); 

        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getEm();
            try {
                $em->beginTransaction();
                $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
                $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
                $user->setSalt(md5(time()));
                $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());
                $user->setPassword($password);
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();
                $em->commit();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $em->rollback();
            }
        }


        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        );
    }
```

I have the Right Form

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'ADV\UserBundle\Entity\User#roles' that was not configured to cascade
>   persist operations for entity: ROLE_WRITER. To solve this issue:
>   Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity
>   or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for
>   example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

But I want to use ManyToMay, and if I add cascade, each time that I create a new User, create also a new Role related